# jsp database querying

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp

I tried to get information about employees' from oracle database.

In JSP, database connection is fine and I also confirmed there's entity in my database.

However, rs2.next() is null when I tried to see on the web.

- I closed conn.close(); before querying.

  ```
  String sql = "select *from member where id like '%" + id
      + "%' and pwd like '%" + pwd + "%'";
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

  (Shows members info)


  String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM commute";

  (Shows working statments)

  Connection conn2;
  Statement stmt2;
  ResultSet rs2;

  rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(sql2);
  %>
  <br>
  <h2>1. Payment Info</h2>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Start to work</td>
          <td>End of work</td>
          <td>Date</td>
          <td>Working hour</td>
      </tr>
      <%
          while(rs2.next()){
      %>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><%=rs2.getString(1)%></td>
          <td><%=rs2.getString(2)%></td>
          <td><%=rs2.getString(3)%></td>
          <td><%=rs2.getString(4)%></td>
          <td><%="DEFAULT" %></td>
      </tr>

  ...
  ```

Comment: where is `stmt2` declared ?

Comment: Does it throws any exception ?

Comment: I edited source. Thanks

Comment: Is this all the code? You are declaring `stmt2` but never assign anything to it before you are trying to execute `stmt2.executeQuery(sql2)`. Seems like some chunks of code missing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally im not a fan of scriptlets.  In this context it violates the principle of single responsibility.  I have written things exactly like this before, and I much prefer doing all the database stuff on the back end, and leaving the JSP's to do JSP stuff, like display the data.

I would grab the data from the database in my DAO, throw it into the model (assuming you have a MVC architecture), then let [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/) iterate through it and display the data.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<table id="results">
  <c:forEach var="item" items="${resultSet}">
    <tr class="even">
      <td id="result"><c:out value="${item.x}" /></td>
      <td id="result"><c:out value="${item.y}" /></td>
      <td id="result"><c:out value="${item.z}" /></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Hope that makes sense!